# jasper report table show previous page total

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using Jaspersoft® Studio 6.8.0.

I want to have a **table** which can show previous page total, take following table for example, assume this
table has **3 pages**:

```
                     grade
                     10
                     20
        sub total    30
                             page 1
                     grade
previous page total  30
                     40
                     50
          sub total  90
                            page 2
                     grade
previous page total  90
                     60
                     70
         sub total   130
                            page 3
```

that is show `previous page total` from 2nd page to last page.

How to achieve that? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to create a variable that holds a mutable value set as a side effect by an expression of the text that displays the total on the previous page.

E.g. something like this:

```
    <variable name="TotalVariable" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum" resetType="Page">
        <variableExpression>$F{Column}</variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="PreviousTotalHolder" class="java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger" calculation="System">
        <initialValueExpression>new java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger()</initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    ...display the previous total in the new page
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement .../>
                            <textFieldExpression>"Previous total " + $V{PreviousTotalHolder}.get()</textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
    ...use a dummy property in the page footer to set the total into the holder object
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="15" uuid="a1ab288e-ae4b-4f12-83a5-e30486bb30d5">
                                <propertyExpression name="foo">Integer.toString($V{PreviousTotalHolder}.getAndSet($V{TotalVariable}))</propertyExpression>
                            </reportElement>
                            <textFieldExpression>"Total " + $V{TotalVariable}</textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
```

There might be other ways to do it depending on the exact design of you report (for instance depending on whether you have a table component or a tabular band report).

Comment: Ok, you can try the solution that I described.  For tabular reports you could have used band return values, but that's not available for table components.

Comment: In jasper studio 6.8.0, I cannot find where to set `propertyExpression` under the `textField`.

Comment: I don't have the same version.  In my instance you can add a property expression like this: select the text element, go to the Properties view, select the Appearance tab, click the Edit Properties at the bottom of the tab, click the "Show properties as table of form" icon in the Properties dialog (right side at the top), click Add, set foo as Property Name, check Use An Expression, write the expression, click OK and Finish.